# Selenium - Clicking Submit button is not navigating to next page

Tags: java, selenium

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class voot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        //WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/dkurugod/Desktop/selenium_tutorials/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        String URL = "https://voting.voot.com/vote/";
        driver.get(URL);
        
        String title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(title);
        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
        
        WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@alt,'Harry')]"));
        
        name.click();
        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
        
        WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Submit']"));
        
        submit.click();
    }}

<button class="jss190"> Submit</button>
```

After clicking on Submit button, it is not navigating to the next page. Can someone please suggest to me how to proceed with this. I am still a beginner in Selenium. Thanks

Comment: add html code or link to the site

Comment: Adding the relevant HTML to the question is a requirement. Adding a link to the site is optional but helpful. The link to the site is in the question but it's not working for me... I get an error when I navigate to the site.

Comment: Was the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

1 You do not need to use this twice:

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

2 For submit button try the following `xpath` locator:

```
//button[contains(@class,'jss190')]
```

Or this:

```
//button[contains(text(),'Submit')]
```

The second locator will only work when there in only one button with type `submit`.